# Segmentation fault in C, malloc array

Tags: c

I have problem with my school project, the server which is testing this build returns this error:

```
./__runscript: line 2: 489 Segmentation fault ./a.out < __input
```

Compile is OK, but this error is displayed just when it starts running. But if I run it on Windows 7 with visual studio 10, everything is fine. I think the mistake might be in the insert() function.

```
POSTUP *insert(POSTUP *first)
{
    POSTUP* current,*pom;
    current=(POSTUP*)malloc(sizeof(POSTUP));
    pom=(POSTUP*)malloc(sizeof(POSTUP));
    int i,count_of_elements;

    scanf("%d", &count_of_elements);

    if(first==NULL)
    {
        first=current;
        first->array= (int*)malloc(count_of_elements*sizeof(int));
        for(i=0; i<count_of_elements; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&first->array[i]);
        }
        first->elements=count_of_elements;
        first->next=NULL;
        return first;
    }
    else
    {
        pom->array= (int*)malloc(count_of_elements*sizeof(int));
        for(i=0; i<count_of_elements; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&pom->array[i]);
        }
        pom->next=NULL;
        pom->elements=count_of_elements;
        current=first;
        while(1)
        {
            if(current->next==NULL)
            {
                current->next=pom;
                return first;
            }   
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int main(void)
{
    int count, i;
    POSTUP* first,*current;
    first= (POSTUP*)malloc(sizeof(POSTUP));
    first=NULL;

    scanf("%d",&count);
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        first=insert(first);

    }
}
```

Comment: `pom` leaks if `first` is `NULL`, and `current` leaks otherwise. Why not just allocate a single new node?

Comment: `scanf("%d",&prvy->array[i]);` -- why not `&first->array[i]` here? what's `prvy`?

Comment: Don't cast the malloc result in C.

Answer (score 1):

This code in `main()`:

```
POSTUP *first, *current;
first = (POSTUP*)malloc(sizeof(POSTUP));
first = NULL;

scanf("%d", &count);
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    first = insert(first);
}
```

is clearly problematic.  You allocate space and store the only pointer to it in `first`; you then overwrite the pointer, leaking memory.  You should officially check that the allocation was not null.  But your `insert()` code is equipped to handle a null pointer as input, so the memory allocation in main is redundant.

In `insert()`, you allocate memory without checking for success; this is a recipe for trouble, though more usually later than sooner.

Your code is never checking the result of `scanf()`; that means you could be getting rubbish into your system if there's a format error in the data.

**Likely cause of crash:** In the 'if (first == NULL)`block in`insert()`, you have:

```
    for(i=0; i<count_of_elements; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &prvy->array[i]);
    }
```

There's no declaration of `prvy` in sight in the code you show; it should almost certainly be referring to `&first->array[i]` anyway.  This could easily be good for a crash.  Otherwise, you've carefully stashed the data in a different set of memory than you thought, so the array for `first` is uninitialized gibberish.

The same code does not use `pom`, so you've leaked memory in this part of the code.

In the main `else` clause in `insert()`, you overwrite `current` (which contained a memory allocation) with `first`, thus leaking memory there too.

Don't allocate memory until you're about to use it.